# MS Graph APIs delta query with expand and nested select parameters not working together

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

MS Graph APIs delta query with **$expand** and nested **$select** parameters not working together in messages.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/MailFolders/Inbox/messages/delta?$expand=attachments($select=name,size)

This request returns all properties in attachments irrespective of selected properties but the same query is working as expected with below request without delta query.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/MailFolders/Inbox/messages?$expand=attachments($select=name,size)

Answer (score 1):

We don't support '$expand' in Delta Query, as described here : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview

Comment: Thanks Anshu for quick response. Delta query supports expand for messages  as described here : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_delta

Comment: Looks like the updated link for Delta Query Overview is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview.  It says: "For the user and group resources, there are restrictions on using some query parameters:$expand is not supported."