# Expand single value extended properties on events delta query?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Should it be possible to provide an `$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties...` query parameter on an events delta request?  My approach returns an error that I wasn't quite expecting.

The request looks like this:

```
API:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0

RESOURCE:
me/calendarView/delta

PARAMS:
startDateTime: 2020-07-01T00:00:00Z
endDateTime: 2021-12-31T23:59:59Z
$expand: singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Boolean {00062002-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x00008229')
```

The request fails, returning this message in the body:

```
Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: initialState
```

It's unclear which value that is referring to, though given that the error does not happen when omitting the $expand I suspect it has something to do with trying to expand in a delta query, or specifying an expand on this/andy extended property.

Omitting the `$expand` results in a successful response, and I am omitting the `$deltatoken` parameter to create a new stream (because existing streams are not encoded with the `$expand`).

You'll nice that the expand is on a non-string type MAPI property, specifically it is the [Invited property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidfinvited-canonical-property). It's explicitly documented that you [cannot $select properties that are not tracked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#properties-stored-outside-of-the-main-data-store), but it doesn't mention whether or not they can be included in the delta response itself.

Is this supposed to be possible? If so, can you point in my the right direction for formatting this request? Thanks!

---

Regarding this [adjacent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347095/ms-graph-apis-delta-query-with-expand-and-nested-select-parameters-not-working-t) that has already been asked.  Seems out of date per the following.

The [Get delta for Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#odata-query-parameters) explicitly states that `$expand` is supported, but the [Get delta for Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#query-parameters) does *not* explicitly state anything about `$expand`, or any OData at all, it just states that `$select` is not supported.

If there is some hidden restriction, can it just be explicitly documented in the events delta documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is actually a bug in the library the service is using, see this [issue](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1162) and that [issue](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1667).
You should be receiving an error saying that the request is not supported.

Even when the parsing bug gets fixed, it's unlikely to work as schema and open extensions are stored in another system than the resource and providing a unique delta token containing a watermark valid for both systems is not implemented today. You can request support for it on [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com).

Comment: "[...] providing a unique delta token containing a watermark valid for both systems is not implemented today" got it, was already aware and prepared for change tracking not to work here, and I think that's fair. Thanks for clarifying that this should actually just be considered unsupported, that answers a big open question about an implementation plan I am working on! Cheers!